# NumPy histogram2d with a rotated, non-orthogonal binning grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, datagrid, histogram2d

I need to compute (and plot) a `histogram2d` but my binning grid is rotated and also non-orthogonal.
A way of doing this could be to apply a transformation to my data so I get it into a cartesian system, compute my `histogram2d` and then apply the inverse transformation.
Can this be done directly without this overhead transformation ?

I guess my question is: how do I define the `bins` for my `histogram2d` in this case ? (AFAIK, `histogram2d` will only accept x and y aligned `bins`)

My data is 2 huge lists of points (10k~100k each), the coordinates of which are given in a cartesian coordinate system (actually a projected CRS because these are real-world locations) but they are organized in a regular grid that is not aligned to X and Y axis (rotated) and that may or may not be orthogonal. The binning grid will be derived from it so it will be a (rotated) regular quadrilaterals grid.

I have seen that `matplotlib` has a `QuadMesh` object ([see here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh)) so I'm being hopeful but I'm not sure how to handle this in `NumPy`.

Basically this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like it might be a job for [`geopandas`](http://geopandas.org/). It does very efficient spatial joins. You might also find [`geofeather`](https://github.com/brendan-ward/geofeather) useful for the speed, but I haven't used it myself.

Comment: @kwinkunks I don't think I need spatial joins, I need to compute the midpoints from pairs coming from my two lists (basically, each and every possible pair) and get a count of these in my non-orthogonal rotated grid. Also, I'm having troubles installing `geopandas` so I'd rather stay away from it if possible.

Comment: Fair enough, it can be a headache to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing, I came to the conclusion that the overhead of transforming the coordinates into a Cartesian grid to compute the histogram and back for plotting is acceptable.  Matrix operations in `NumPy` are fairly efficient and I can handle 115+ million points in less than 7 sec.

However, the "back" part can be handled by `Matplotlib` directly with `matplotlib.transforms`.
`pcolormesh`, `hist2d` and `imshow` all accept a `transform` keyword which can be used to plot the Cartesian data into the desired coordinates like so:

```
# set I, J, bins (in the Cartesian system) and cmap
# a, b, c, d, e, f are values of the transformation matrix
transform = matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D.from_values(a, b, c, f, d, e, f)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
_, _, _, im = ax.hist2d(I, J, bins=bins, cmap=cmap, transform=transform + ax.transData)
fig.colorbar(im)
ax.autoscale()
```

It is not really much faster than handling the "back" conversion with `NumPy` but it can make the code lighter as it only requires 1 additional line and 1 additional keyword.
`imshow` can be a little bit of a pain as it won't update the display extent after using `ax.autoscale()` and it handles coordinates as images or matrix so the `transform` has to be adjusted accordingly. For these reasons, I prefer `hist2d`.

References:

1. https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/transformations.html#module-matplotlib.transforms
2. https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html